# How to have New and Save buttons outside the corresponding route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a challenge that is easy to explain by picture:
[Explanation of ApplicationController and ArticlesController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr2j3.png)

What I want is, when I hit save, that the `saveArticle` action is called within the `App.ArticlesNewController`.

**The template**

```
<div class="buttonBlock">
    {{#linkTo "articles.new" class="newButton"}}Nieuw{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo action="saveArticle" class="newButton storeButton"}}Opslaan{{/linkTo}} // generates an error: "This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid. "
</div>
```

**Routes**

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('articles', {path: "/articles"}, function() {
        this.resource('article', {path: '/:article_id'}); // works fine
        this.route('new', {path: "/new"}); // displays also without errors
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        // got never called
        saveArticle: function () {
            console.log('ApplicationRoute saveArticle action');
            this.controllerFor('articles.new').send('saveArticle')
        }
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
App.ArticlesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function () {
        console.log('ArticlesNewRoute try to render article with controller articles.new');
        this.render('article', {
            controller: 'articles.new'
        });
    },
    model: function () {
        console.log('ArticlesNewRoute returning model');
        return this.store.createRecord('article');
    },

    actions: {
        // this will never be called
        saveArticle: function () { 
            console.log('ArticlesNewRoute saveArticle action');
            this.currentModel.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Note, currently I have the actions for a new article in the `App.ArticlesNewRoute` what obviously will not work currently with the `this.controllerFor('articles.new').send('saveArticle')` call.

The real problem with the saveArticle action is, that it is also never calling within the `App.ApplicationController`.

I have also used `{{controller}}` in my template. And I am sure that the buttons in the template are handled by the `App.ApplicationController`, however the call is never fired.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you intending to put other models in the outlet where articles go? IE, will new and save eventually also be used to control other models too?

Comment: @Michael Johnston, to they are just there to create a new Article. When I was about to sleep last night I thought: maybe I just add the buttons to the article view and I am done. And I think that is exactly what you want to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issues in your code

1) `link-to` is used only for routes. In your case I suggest follow below.

```
<a class="newButton storeButton" {{action "saveArticle"}}>Opslaan</a>
```

2) You shouldn't use `this.controllerFor()` in controller. As far as i remember, it is deprecated.It is only available in routes currently. You should use `needs` and try to access controller from that. Follow the link for more Info on `needs`.

http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/